# Is there a way to schedule a Nifi Controller Service to update periodically

Tags: apache-nifi

I need my NiFi Controller Service to update periodically. Is there a way to achieve this?

**For more information:**
I have two files **1. Customer_Info** and **2. Sales_Info**

`Customer_Info` file contains information like `cust_id`, `name`, `address`.

`Sales_Info` contains information like `sales_id`, `cust_id` ,`date_id`.

Both the files are received daily. Now, I want to merge these two files in NiFi. For this, I'm using **CSVRecordLookupService** lookup service. But once the files is loaded, I don't see a way to reload it with new file received.

Answer (score 2):

It would be up to each controller service to implement the logic to periodically update itself since it is dependent on whatever the controller service is doing.

Unfortunately the CsvRecordLookupService does not periodically update itself, but I think an enhancement could be implemented to make it do this. An example of one that does update itself is the PropertiesFileLookupService.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan! Interestingly, in NiFi 1.8, the CSVRecordLookupService is said to be reloadable controller service. Having said that, I don't see any configuration in PropertiesFileLookupService to set up how frequently the controller service should be reloaded. Can you please provide any information related to that?

Comment: Actually you are correct, looking at it again, the CSVRecordLookupService will reload the file every 30 seconds if it has changed. The PropertiesFileLookupService I am not sure what the interval is, I just know it will reload, it is based on apache commons configuration ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder

Comment: Thanks @Bryan! The CSVRecordLookupService worked. It reloaded the new file.